# ASP.NET - jQuery DataTables requested unknown parameter error

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I using ASP.NET MVC 5 to make a web app, and in my view to list movies and their genres I get this error:

> DataTables warning: table id=movies - Requested unknown parameter 'genre.name' for row 0, column 1. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4

My script in my view:

```
 var table = $("#movies").DataTable({
            ajax: {
                url: "/api/movies",
                dataSrc: ""
            },
            columns: [
                {
                    data: "name",
                    render: function(data, type, movie) {
                        return "<a href='/movies/edit/" + movie.id + "'>" + movie.name + "</a>";
                    }
                },
                {
                    data: "genre.name"
                },
                {
                    data: "id",
                    render: function(data) {
                        return "<button class='btn-link js-delete' data-movie-id=" + data + ">Delete</button>";
                    }
                }
            ]
```

I believe that the `genre.name`code is the issue. The genre model simply has two fields and takes it's info from the database. Thank you for the help.

Here is the get method in my api/movies controller:

```
 public IEnumerable<MovieDto> GetMovies()
    {
        return _context.Movies
            .Include(m => m.GenreSet)
            .ToList()
            .Select(Mapper.Map<Movie, MovieDto>);
    }
```

The `MovieDto` class has a member field `GenreSetDto` which has been mapped from my `GenreSet` class.

Edit: 
Here is the data I am getting:

```
[
 {
"id": 1,
"name": "Hangover",
"genreId": 0,
"genre": null,
"dateAdded": "2009-04-03T00:00:00",
"releaseDate": "2009-02-03T00:00:00",
"numberInStock": 5
 }
 ]
```

I see now, that the issue is the genreId is zero which is null because I don't have a genre corresponding to that in the database. The genreId shouldn't be zero though, it should be 2 as I assigned it in the movie database.

Comment: You have `name` and `genre.name` in your data response?

Comment: I'm not sure what that means, I'm sorry. `name` has no issue rendering when I load the page though, only `genre.name`.

Comment: What is return `/api/movies`???

Comment: @ecain You should post your JSON data that is being sent from the server to the client, as that will probably be the source of your `genre.name` bug. That's probably what CMedina means; you're getting this error because there isn't a `genre.name` object in the JSON data.

Comment: @CMedina `/api/movies` is the web api controller. @Chris H. When I use postman to view my JSON data I just get Unexpected '<' as the result. Is there another way to view my JSON data?

Comment: try this... Copy `/api/movies` url in your navigator

Comment: I did that and made an edit. It looks like my the genre field for some reason is not going through correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like the "Genre" property is not included in your api call, if you are using Entity Framework check if the generated sql included foreign tables?

Comment: The genre property should be included though shouldn't it? The movie model has the genre field. How do I check if the generated sql includes foreign table?

Comment: I think this article can help you, please take a look
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/data/jj574232.aspx

Answer (score -1):

Add GenreDto to MovieDto class, and it should work.

```cs
public class MovieDto {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(255)]
    public string MovieName { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ReleaseDate { get; set; }
    //public DateTime? DateAdded { get; set; }
    public byte NumberInStock { get; set; }
    public int MovieGenreId { get; set; }
    public GenreDto Genre { get; set; }
}
```